# How to disable compression of initrd.img file of Debian Linux 10 buster

Tags: linux, debian, initramfs, compression

I want to disable compression of `/boot/initrd.img` file to boot a bit faster. My disk is large enough to accomodate the extra 10MB. To be honest I think that should be the default, who can't afford some megabytes of disk space nowadays. For embedded scenarios, it could be manually enabled.

Looking into `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`, there are options to change the compression type

```
COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz ]
```

but no option to disable compression. I tried `None` and `none`, no effect.

As a workabout I manually decompress `initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64` using `gunzip`. But each time a kernel update is installed I have to decompress again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s no option provided to do this, but since `mkinitramfs` is a shell script, one can be added without needing to recompile. In `/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs`, look for

```
case "${compress}" in
```

Add a “cat” line in the set of options:

```
cat)   compress="cat" ;;
```

This will allow `COMPRESS=cat` to be specified in `initramfs.conf`.

You will have to re-do this every time `mkinitramfs` is restored from the package (on upgrade).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't strike as something easy to do nowadays, certainly not an obvious option under `initramfs.conf`.

The total time taken to read and decompressing the image is the sum of reading the file and decompressing it. The 1st task is i/o bound, the 2nd is mostly CPU bound.

Therefore the comparison between loading a compressed vs an uncompressed image isn't direct. In one case you read a smaller file then decompress it, in the other you read a larger file but don't decompress.

Which one is faster, you'll need to benchmark. If I were to guess, I'd say reading a smaller file and decompressing.

Comment: The difference here is very dependent on storage speed, memory speed, and CPU speed. A lot of systems I work with actually are faster using LZ4 than any of the higher compression ratio options, and I have a few that actually _do_ boot noticeably faster with no compression at all (mostly VMs running emulated CPUs, so compression/decompression on them is _super_ slow, even for LZ4).

Answer (score 2):

You can change `COMPRESS=gzip` to `COMPRESS=cat` in `initramfs.conf`
It will give a warning message when creating images, just ignore it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Kitt gave good advice, but it does not work now on Debian 11, because the `-c` flag is used when calling the compressor binary file, which breaks the `cat` operation.

Also, a good solution would not be to edit `/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs` every time.
The most elegant for me was the `pv` instead of a compressor into `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`. It prompts a small warning, but doesn't break the job:

> user@s:~# time update-initramfs -c -k all
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64
> W: Unknown compression command pv
> 134MiB 0:00:00 [ 220MiB/s] [==================================>] 100%
> real    0m9,144s
> user    0m4,915s
> sys     0m3,654s
> user@s:~#

Comment: The question is about how to make boot faster by booting from an uncompressed image file.  How have you answered that question?  The only thing I can see is that you’ve added some (trivial?) amount of overhead by running `pv`.  If you mean for your answer to be a delta to Stephen’s answer, don’t do that.  Quote enough of his answer that yours makes sense by itself.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Interesting point, the one about `-c` flag breaking `cat`.

Comment: Will use gzip if no compatible compressor is found